# How to remove empty columns in R?

Tags: r, csv

I have a CSV file

```
Identity,Number,Data,Result,Add,,,,,,,,,,,,
1,,,,4,55,,92,,,,,,,,,62,
3,,,,7,43,,12,,,,,,,,,74,
7,,,,3,58,,52,,,,,,,,,64,
0,,,,6,10,,22,,,,,,,,,96,
3,,,,8,13,,92,,,,,,,,,22,
```

How to remove empty columns in R?

Desired Output

```
Identity,Number,Data,Result,Add
1,4,55,92,62
3,7,43,12,74
7,3,58,52,64
0,6,10,22,96
3,8,13,92,22
```

Answer (score 15):

After you've imported your data (using the method the other answerer suggested) run this command, substituting `mydf` for whatever you decide to call your data frame:

```
#Remove empty columns
mydf <- Filter(function(x)!all(is.na(x)), mydf)
```

Comment: For some reasons, this does not work with the example from this post https://www.codingprof.com/3-easy-ways-to-remove-empty-columns-in-r

Answer (score 3):

Convert the empty cell to NA and then remove the NAs

```
mydata[mydata == ""] <- NA
mydata<- mydata[,colSums(is.na(mydata)) < <a desired filter value>]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [remove_empty](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/janitor/versions/1.1.1/topics/remove_empty) from [janitor](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/janitor/versions/1.1.1)

Using the input from Thomas's post:

```
> mydf

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18
1  1 NA NA NA  4 55 NA 92 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  62  NA
2  3 NA NA NA  7 43 NA 12 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  74  NA
3  7 NA NA NA  3 58 NA 52 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  64  NA
4  0 NA NA NA  6 10 NA 22 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  96  NA
5  3 NA NA NA  8 13 NA 92 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  22  NA

> mydf %>% remove_empty("cols")

1  1  4 55 92  62
2  3  7 43 12  74
3  7  3 58 52  64
4  0  6 10 22  96
5  3  8 13 92  22
```

Answer (score 2):

A more complex removal logic is like this:

```
mydf <- Filter(function(x)!all(is.na(x) || is.null(x) || x == "" || x == 0), mydf)
```

Answer (score 1):

If we have limited columns like you have in this case, below would be neat workaround.

```
myDF<-myDF[,c(1,2,3,4,5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the data file, excluding the header row:

```
mydf <- 
read.csv(text='Identity,Number,Data,Result,Add
1,,,,4,55,,92,,,,,,,,,62,
3,,,,7,43,,12,,,,,,,,,74,
7,,,,3,58,,52,,,,,,,,,64,
0,,,,6,10,,22,,,,,,,,,96,
3,,,,8,13,,92,,,,,,,,,22,', header=FALSE, skip=1)
```

Then load just the header row:

```
n <- read.csv(text='Identity,Number,Data,Result,Add', header=TRUE)
```

Then use the names from `n` to assign names to the full data, excluding `NA` columns:

```
setNames(mydf[,sapply(mydf, function(x) all(!is.na(x)))],names(n))
```

Note, if you have this saved as a file, the full code should be:

```
mydf <- read.csv('file.csv', header=FALSE, skip=1)
n <- read.csv('file.csv', header=TRUE, nrows=1)
setNames(mydf[,sapply(mydf, function(x) all(!is.na(x)))],names(n))
```

Comment: I have edited my question, now there are equal number of commas in the header as well, so basically it's being read as 16 cols instead of 5, how to solve the problem, and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

How about you keep only those columns which name is not blank?

```
> mydf <- mydf[,names(mydf)!=""]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fancy function I sometimes use for fun. Note that it is not robust - it searches the complete environment for a `.data` data set, which `dplyr` puts there if running `select()` so it depends on their internal framework (which might change):

```r
empty_cols <- function(x) {
  for (frm in sys.frames()) {
    if (is.data.frame(frm$.data)) {
      df <- frm$.data
      return(which(sapply(df, function(col) all(is.na(col)))))
    }
  }
  # found nothing, return NULL to return no columns:
  NULL
}
```

Now select using:

```r
library(dplyr)
my_df %>% select(!empty_cols())
```

Would've been great if we could just use `dplyr::pick(everything())` in this function, but they have limited the use to `mutate()`, `filter()` and `group_by()`...