# How in R one can do away with empty columns?

Tags: r, csv

I have a CSV file like

```
Identity,AdvertiserName,CampaignName,AdGroupName,Keyword,DestURL,KeystoneKW,,CampaignDuplicate,AdGroupDuplicate,CampaignLocation,,,,,,,,,
666,Bro Pest Control,cat|home & garden|pest control,kw|entry,Bro Pest Control,http://www.ci.com/profile/66/ab/brrd_pest_control.html,Pest Control,,NO,NO,"Ablle,Louna,United States",,,,,,,,,
447,Dist Tire Ctr Inc,cat|automotive sales & services|automotive repair,kw|entry,DisTire Ctr Inc,http://www.cit.com/profile/44/abbeville_la/discoutire_ctr_inc.html,Autepair,,NO,NO,"Abblle,Louana,United States",,,,,,,,,
6665,Best Control,geo|la|abbe la area,home & garden|pest control,Br Pest Control,http://www.cit.com/profile/66/abbee_la/broud_pest_control.html,Pest Control,,NO,NO,"A,Louisiana,United States",,,,,,,,,
```

My desired output is

```
 Identity,AdvertiserName,CampaignName,AdGroupName,Keyword,DestURL,KeystoneKW,,CampaignDuplicate,AdGroupDuplicate,CampaignLocation
666,Broud Pest Control,cat|home & garden|pest control,kw|entry,Bssad Pest Control,http://www.cit.com/profile/666/abbeville_la/brrd_pest_control.html,Pest Control,NO,NO,"Abbe,Louiana,United States"
44,DiscTire Ctr Inc,cat|automotive sales & services|automotive repair,kw|entry,Discount Tire Ctr Inc,http://www.cit.com/profile/44/ab/discouctr_inc.html,Automotive Repair,NO,NO,"Abbe,Loua,United States"
```

The piece of code I am using is

```
mydf <- read.csv("C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/FinalLocationList1.csv", header=FALSE, skip=1)
d <- setNames(mydf[,sapply(mydf, function(x) all(!is.na(x)))],names(n))
z <- mydf <- Filter(function(x)!all(is.na(x)), mydf)
```

Credit - Thomas

But the above is not taking care of the Header problem? How to solve it? New to R. 
Any help is appreciated.

Edit : Output of dput(mydf)

```
structure(list(V1 = c(666L, 447L, 6665L), V2 = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 1L), .Label = c("Best Control", "Bro Pest Control", "Dist Tire Ctr Inc"
), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("cat|automotive sales &   services|automotive repair", 
"cat|home & garden|pest control", "geo|la|abbe la area"), class = "factor"), 
V4 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("home & garden|pest control", 
"kw|entry"), class = "factor"), V5 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 
1L), .Label = c("Br Pest Control", "Bro Pest Control", "DisTire Ctr Inc"
), class = "factor"), V6 = structure(1:3, .Label = c("http://www.ci.com/profile/66/ab /brrd_pest_control.html", 
"http://www.cit.com/profile/44/abbeville_la/discoutire_ctr_inc.html", 
"http://www.cit.com/profile/66/abbee_la/broud_pest_control.html"
), class = "factor"), V7 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Autepair", 
"Pest Control"), class = "factor"), V8 = c(NA, NA, NA), V9 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "NO", class = "factor"), V10 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "NO", class = "factor"), V11 = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("A,Louisiana,United States", "Abblle,Louana,United States", 
"Ablle,Louna,United States"), class = "factor"), V12 = c(NA, 
NA, NA), V13 = c(NA, NA, NA), V14 = c(NA, NA, NA), V15 = c(NA, 
NA, NA), V16 = c(NA, NA, NA), V17 = c(NA, NA, NA), V18 = c(NA, 
NA, NA), V19 = c(NA, NA, NA), V20 = c(NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", 
"V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", "V17", "V18", "V19", "V20"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Error

```
Error in setNames(mydf[, sapply(mydf, function(x) all(!is.na(x)))], names(n)) : 
'names' attribute [20] must be the same length as the vector [10]
```

Comment: you are in right track, after reding `mydf`, i guess now your mydf is 8 col, so delete those 3 cols by `mydf<-mydf[,-c(2,5,7)]` and just use `names(mydf)<-c("Identity",......)`

Comment: It would be easier to replace ",," with "," using a text editor prior to reading the file with R. If you can use sed it would even be faster.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove empty columns in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104962/how-to-remove-empty-columns-in-r)

Comment: It's fairly easy to see that you want `header=TRUE` since the first column is 'numeric'.

Comment: It is true that it is the same question but none of the the answers described the way to do this as part of the input operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `colClasses="NULL"` for the columns you want to drop ... the last nine in this case, so `rep("NULL",9)`

```
tx <- 'Identity,AdvertiserName,CampaignName,AdGroupName,Keyword,DestURL,KeystoneKW,,CampaignDuplicate,AdGroupDuplicate,CampaignLocation,,,,,,,,,
666,Broud Pest Control,cat|home & garden|pest control,kw|entry,Bssad Pest Control,http://www.cit.com/profile/666/abbeville_la/brrd_pest_control.html,Pest Control,,NO,NO,"Abbe,Louiana,United States",,,,,,,,,
44,DiscTire Ctr Inc,cat|automotive sales & services|automotive repair,kw|entry,Discount Tire Ctr Inc,http://www.cit.com/profile/44/ab/discouctr_inc.html,Automotive Repair,,NO,NO,"Abbe,Loua,United States",,,,,,,,,'

df <- read.table(text=tx, sep=",", 
                 colClasses=c("numeric", rep("character",10), rep("NULL",9)), 
                 header=TRUE)

> str(df)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ Identity         : num  666 44
 $ AdvertiserName   : chr  "Broud Pest Control" "DiscTire Ctr Inc"
 $ CampaignName     : chr  "cat|home & garden|pest control" "cat|automotive sales & services|automotive repair"
 $ AdGroupName      : chr  "kw|entry" "kw|entry"
 $ Keyword          : chr  "Bssad Pest Control" "Discount Tire Ctr Inc"
 $ DestURL          : chr  "http://www.cit.com/profile/666/abbeville_la/brrd_pest_control.html" "http://www.cit.com/profile/44/ab/discouctr_inc.html"
 $ KeystoneKW       : chr  "Pest Control" "Automotive Repair"
 $ X                : chr  "" ""
 $ CampaignDuplicate: chr  "NO" "NO"
 $ AdGroupDuplicate : chr  "NO" "NO"
 $ CampaignLocation : chr  "Abbe,Louiana,United States" "Abbe,Loua,United States"
```

Comment: The result has 11 columns instead of 10 though I did remove it. Thanks for  the answer I have been searching  for a while. got to learn something new.

Comment: Yeah. I didn't notice until later that you had an embedded bpty column but that could be handled with `c("numeric", rep("character",6), "NULL, rep("character", 3), rep("NULL",9)), `

Comment: +1, Nice trick.  Documented, though I didn't notice it when scanning for an obvious argument to do just this.

Comment: @BrodieG,@IShould c("numeric", rep("character",6), "NULL, rep("character", 3), rep("NULL",9)) seems so  there is an error should it be like c("numeric", rep("character",6), rep("NULL",7),rep("character", 3), rep("NULL",9)) - but then it shows error - more columns than column names.

Comment: Missing double quote after the first NULL.  `c("numeric", rep("character",6), "NULL", rep("character", 3), rep("NULL",9)),`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
    setNames(
      Filter(function(x) !all(is.na(x)), mydf), 
      names(mydf)[-grep("^X(\\.[0-9]+)?$", names(mydf))]
    )
```

Produces:

```
  Identity Number Data Result Add
1        1      4   55     92  62
2        3      7   43     12  74
3        7      3   58     52  64
4        0      6   10     22  96
5        3      8   13     92  22
```

`Filter` will keep all columns that are not all `NA`.  Then the grep piece relies on the names produced by read.CSV for blank columns (X, X.1, etc.) to filter out the wrong names.  This should work generically.

---

EDIT: running with updated CSV produces:

```
> str(setNames(Filter(function(x) !all(is.na(x)), mydf), names(mydf)[-grep("^X(\\.[0-9]+)?", names(mydf))]))
'data.frame': 2 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ Identity         : int  666 44
 $ AdvertiserName   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Broud Pest Control",..: 1 2
 $ CampaignName     : Factor w/ 2 levels "cat|automotive sales & services|automotive repair",..: 2 1
 $ AdGroupName      : Factor w/ 1 level "kw|entry": 1 1
 $ Keyword          : Factor w/ 2 levels "Bssad Pest Control",..: 1 2
 $ DestURL          : Factor w/ 2 levels "http://www.cit.com/profile/44/ab/discouctr_inc.html",..: 2 1
 $ KeystoneKW       : Factor w/ 2 levels "Automotive Repair",..: 2 1
 $ CampaignDuplicate: Factor w/ 1 level "NO": 1 1
 $ AdGroupDuplicate : Factor w/ 1 level "NO": 1 1
 $ CampaignLocation : Factor w/ 2 levels "Abbe,Loua,United States",..: 2 1
```

Comment: Edited my question as well to the actual csv file, please take a look at it and in the meanwhile I will try the new edit as well.

Comment: @user3188390, the code seems to work with your file, at least for me.

Comment: The output is stating there are 19 columns instead of just 10. why? I am using the code like : mydf <- read.csv("C:/Users/Administrator/Downloads/FinalLocationList.csv",header=TRUE); z <- setNames(Filter(function(x) !all(is.na(x)), mydf), names(mydf)[-grep("^X(\\.[0-9]+)?", names(mydf))]);

Comment: Can you `dput(mydf)` and update your question with it?  Hard to know for sure without working directly with your data.

Comment: Changed the input and as requested the output of dput(mydf) along with the error

Comment: Got the answer, I appreciate your help. I have also posted the updated question for your reference.