# What is the most efficient way to remove empty columns in a datatable in R

Tags: r, datatable, null, data-manipulation

I have some import issues with a file, that create an empty column at the end such as :

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
MWE <- data.table(var1=c(1,2),var2=c(3,4),var3=c(NA,NA))
```

Now I can remove it easily as I know the empty column is the last one :

```
MWE2 <- MWE[,c(length(MWE)):=NULL]
```

But I wondered how I would do if I just wanted to remove a random empty column without knowing its number. A quick search here and on the datatable page gave me a lot of examples on how to :

- remove empty lines in datatables, through `na.omit`
- remove empty columns in a dataframe, for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104962/how-to-remove-empty-columns-in-r)

But I did not find solutions to remove empty columns in datatables. What are the options and which is the fastest ?

Comment: Here is a relevant post with dplyr solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49374887/piping-the-removal-of-empty-columns-using-dplyr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could check if `all` values are `NA` in a column, get the column name and assign those to NULL

```
nm1 <- MWE[, names(which(sapply(.SD, function(x) all(is.na(x)))))] 
# or
# nm1 <- MWE[, names(which(!colSums(!is.na(.SD))))]
MWE[, (nm1) := NULL]
```

---

Or with `Filter`

```
MWE[, Filter(function(x) any(!is.na(x)), .SD)]
```

---

Or using `select`

```
library(dplyr)
MWE %>%
     select(where(~ any(!is.na(.))))
```

Comment: How do we handle the first version for caes where `nm1` is empty (no columns have all `NA`)? Do we just wrap `MWE[, (nm1) := NULL]` in a check for `length(nm1) > 0`?

Comment: @Therkel if it returns nothing also it should work `dt1 <- as.data.table(head(iris));
> nm1 <- intersect('hello', names(dt1));dt1[, (nm1) := NULL]`